# Uniform distribution symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

What is the symbol for uniform distribution in LaTeX? I'm assuming that it is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) symbol? Or should I just use a simple U?

Comment: If you want to copy the symbol Wikipedia uses, it's `$\mathcal{U}$`.

Comment: Would you consider that as the correct notation for a uniform distribution?

Comment: I'd say that depends on your field. I haven't seen a dedicated symbol for the uniform distribution so far, but I'm not a professional Statistician.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no standard symbol for a uniform distribution. (The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) page  mentions “U” in italic in text but an image of a calligraphic “U” in summary table; this is inconsistent and non-authoritative.)

So you can use whatever symbol you prefer, preferably following normal conventions for using symbols. Using “U” in italics is certainly acceptable.

Comment: A number of first year statistics texts use the notation n($\mu$,$\sigma$), the n may be upper or lower case, or itialics; and it may be $\sigma$ or $\sigma^2$.  No standard notation.

Comment: And the cumulative standard normal is often denoted with $\phi(z)$ with z being the upper limit of the integration of the standard normal  probability density function.

Comment: thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I checked my own statistics book and they use a simple U as well.

Comment: @R.Schumacher It appears that you're referring to the [Normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), not to the _Uniform_ distribution which was in question. The former is depicted as a bell curve and as such is quite different from the latter, which yields a constant graph.

Answer (score 3):

I often see this:

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\unif}{\pazocal{U}}
```

Comment: A more modern way to do this might be to load Asana Math in `unicode-math`, or the `px` calligraphic alphabet in `mathalpha`, and use `\mathcal{U}`.